# Dynamic htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out how to setup some redirects in my htaccess file.

We load our stores with dynamic urls for example:

/locations/new-york

new-york being the dynamic part

We have old urls that contain different path such as

/locations/new-york/local-store

I want to be able to take all locations/dynamic-city and forward them to the new URL

So

/locations/new-york/local-store/offers

should goto /locations/new-york/current-offers

Comment: Is it always /locations/{location}/local-store/offers or are there other urls?

Comment: There are others, but all follow a similar method

Comment: What are they? You might be able to cover them all in 1 RewriteRule rather than having separate ones. Just depends on what they are.

Comment: /locations/{location}/local-store/hot-tubs to /location/{location}/hot-tubs || 
/locations/{location}/local-store/pre-owned to /location/{location}/pre-owned ||

/locations/{location}/local-store/client-reviews to /location/{location}/reviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)/local-store/offers locations/$1/current-offers [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)/local-store/hot-tubs locations/$1/hot-tubs [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)/local-store/pre-owned locations/$1/pre-owned [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)/local-store/client-reviews locations/$1/reviews [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Ok, so I'm not seeing a way to easily use 1 rewriterule to cover all 4 cases. But you can see make sure the requested url following a pattern like this.

```
^locations/{location}/local-store/offers
```

Then you take the location and place it into the new url you want to write it to.

```
L     # means it's the last rule, don't try to match anymore
R=301 # means redirect the old url to the new one
QSA   # means append any query string parameters to the new url
```